# Ancho columnas Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy intentado a la hora de hacer una web con Bootstrap 5 y me gustaría que el diseño fuera el siguiente,

ColumnaIzquierda - ColumnaCentral(Con el contenido) - ColumnaDerecha

Las columnas laterales es solo para poner un color y ya y todo el contenido de la web iría en la columna central.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1" id="left">
      IZQUIERDA
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      CONTENIDO
    </div>
    <div class="col-1" id="right">
     DERECHA
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Y el css que estoy usando es:

```
body{
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.row{
  height: 100%;
  
}
#right,#left{
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  

 }
```

Si miramos la web se queda (de izquierda a derecha) blanco-gris-blanco-gris-blanco y quiero que sea gris-blanco-gris
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es más fácil utilizar un container, añadirle el contenido y darle color de fondo al body?

Comment: No lo había visto de ese modo...

Comment: Para esto está el Stack!! Animo con eso, piensa siempre en optimizar código

Comment: No entiendo tu error, el código hace justo lo que dices, en orden L-R : gris, blanco, gris. Tal como tu imagen.

Answer (score -1):

Colocale al div container: `class="container-fluid"`
Necesitas hacer esto para tener un contenedor de todo el ancho de la pantalla. Así el grid que estás creando se ajusta correctamente a la pantalla.

Comment: Editada la respuesta, saludos